# Why my function is not being print after map?

Tags: scala, chaining

I am trying to figure it out how to chain functions in Scala.

I have the following code:

```
def multiPrint(list: List[Int], number: Int): Unit = {
    list
      .map(x => x * number)
      .andThen(x => print(x))
  }
```

but this does not print a result as I expected. It prints `"()"` like if it was an empty list.

Then I tried like:

```
  def multiPrint(list: List[Int], number: Int): Unit = {
      list
        .toStream
        .map(x => x * number)
        .print
  }
```

This works, but `toStream` is deprecated. Anyway, I would like to do it with `andThen`. Any idea?

Comment: You want to print each element of the list? Or the whole list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer mentioned, you are looking for `foreach` ...
But I thought, I'd explain what `andThen` actually does here, which is kinda interesting.

So, if you look at a signature of `andThen`:

```
trait PartialFunction[A, B] extends (A => B) { 
...
   def andThen[C](k: B => C): PartialFunction[A, C]
...
}
```

it should become clear that it doesn't do what you think it does.
It is actually a partial function *combinator*: given two partial functions, one f1: A => B, and and another f2: B => C, it creates and returns a third function, A => C, that first calls `f1` with the given argument, *and then* invokes `f2` with the result of execution of `f1`.

So,

```
 list
      .map(_ * number)
      .andThen(print(_))
```

Does not really print *anything* at all (I am guessing your saw `()` in the output when because you tried to print out the *result* of `multiPrint`, which is a `Unit`.

But, if you try something like this:

```
val foo = Seq(1,2,3).map(_ * 2).antThen(print(_))
foo(1)
```

You may get mildly surprised because this prints 4. `foo(2)` will print 6. and `foo(3)`? It throws an `IndexOutOfBoundException` which may give you a hint on what's really going on.

`Seq[Int]` in scala is actually a `PartialFunction[Int, Int]`, that returns the `Seq` element at the index given by the argument. Your `.andThen` combined that function with `print`, and created a new function `foo`, that accesses the element of the result of `.map` at the given index, *andThen* prints the result.

So, `foo(1)` for instance, gets the element at index 1, which is `2*2`, and prints 4. And `foo(3)` fails, because index 3 does not exist.

A note just for the sake of completness:

As the other answer mentions, to print out elements of seq one-by-one,
just use `foreach`: `Seq(1,2,3).map(_ *2).foreach(println)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same format as `.toStream.print`, then use `mkString(", ")` and then print the resulting string:

```scala
def multiPrint(list: List[Int], number: Int): Unit = {
    val string = list.map(x => x * number).mkString(", ")
    print(string)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for it `foreach`, which is the "cousin" of `map` which rather than transforming a collection applies some sort of side effect (like printing).

```
def multiPrint(list: List[Int], number: Int): Unit = {
    list
      .map(x => x * number)
      .foreach(print)
  }

multiPrint(List(1,2,3), 2) // prints 246
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/3VHU4QvATBWhRedxyulLCQ).

Remember to use `println` if you want to have a newline after each number. ;-)